# ASP authentication using Facebook or LinkedIn

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication, linkedin-api

I need to integrate Facebook and LinkedIn authentication in my asp.net application. I am guessing someone already did this but can't find a pointer. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Facebook authentication**,

Please read [Authentication - Facebook Developers](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication).

More easier, using [Facebook SDK](http://facebooksdk.codeplex.com/)

**For LinkedIn authentication**,

Please read [LinkedIn Authentication](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication)

More easier, [C# LinkedIn api entegration working example](http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1230)

**Integrate with your website**

1. You can make a own custom membership/role/profile etc and don't use the built in approach.
2. Another way, after authenticating successful Facebook or LinkedIn, you should create new member depend on authentication content that you was received, and store User ID in database and map it with Facebook, LinkedIn ID.

Sorry by bad English